# Cannot format USB Drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, format, drive

I had this USB drive that I did not use for a long time and decided to format it.

But apparently it cannot be formated, because everytime I even delete a folder inside it, the folder comes back after I reinsert the drive.

I don't know what to do anymore to make the flash drive work again.

[Drive on Disk Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THOtb.png)

Update: I tried to erase the partition table by running this code at terminal:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

The terminal just freezes and nothing happens.

Comment: If it can't be formatted using Disks, it is probably dead. In the good old days a flash drive was good for 10000 to 1000000 writes, nowadays some are good for less than 500 writes.

Answer (score 0):

Install gparted.  Make new partition table on the thumb drive and choose gpt.  Then create a new partition for the drive. Fat-32 is easiest for all operating systems.  If only for Ubuntu then ext4 is great.  Between Linux and Windows NTFS works fastest with the least limitations.

Comment: When i click apply to create the partition table gparted freezes.

Comment: OK well done trying. I assume you had a live version of Gparted or even the Ubuntu one should be fine. It is probably a dead flash drive.  There are times when the lock flag gets thrown when a thumb drive gets moved between operating systems.  Usually between Mac and Linux.  There are ways to recover but with the low cost of flash memory it may not be worth it as it could lock again just after you have something important on it.